# How to use isset inside an if correctly in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I am creating a website where I have 3 variables brought from a post method, I am using isset to define if it exists, everything will depend on a form that is inside the condition if it exists, but at the moment of sending the form to the same page, the following variable does not show me any data, this is my code to make it more understandable.

Here I define my 3 variables brought by POST:

```
    $con_in_recepcion_es = $_POST['con_in_recepcion_es'];
$con_in_recepcion_eng = $_POST['con_in_recepcion_eng'];
$con_in_recepcion_ori  = $_POST['con_in_recepcion_ori'];
```

Here if the condition is met, it goes to the other but not showing the result of the variable

```
<?php  if(isset($con_in_recepcion_es)){?>
    <div class="container contenerdor_dideo">
    <iframe src="<?php echo $con_in_recepcion_es; ?>" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    <form method="POST" action="auditorio.php" name="formulario1">
    <input type="text" name="con_in_recepcion_ori" value="<?php echo $con_in_recepcion_ori ?>">
    <input type="text" name="con_in_recepcion_esp" value="<?php echo $con_in_recepcion_es ?>">
    </div><a href="javascript:enviar_formulario()" onclick="window.location='auditorio.php'"  ><div id="button-forum-plenarios" >
    <i class="fas fa-globe iconForo"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Audio Original</b>  </div></a>
     </form>
<?php }elseif(isset($con_in_recepcion_ori)){  ?>
    <input type="text" name="con_in_recepcion_ori" value="<?php echo $con_in_recepcion_esp ?>">
<?php }?>
```

That is, the value of the variable is not displayed $con_in_recepcion_esp  If it is already defined when starting the file, am I doing it right?

Comment: What is the actual html output? what is being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

`isset` only checks that variable is created and isn't null.

So your post values are being set however they might not have any data and could just be empty strings. For example if this post data is coming from a form the variables will be set but if the user didn't enter anything their will be no data.

Make sure to use `empty` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php to check to see if your variables have a non empty value.

```
<?php  if(isset($con_in_recepcion_es) && !empty(con_in_recepcion_es)){?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the variables already defined have a data since this data is defined it is always a url of a video

Answer (score -1):

Please write your code this format.

`<?PHP if(isset($con_in_recepcion_es) && $con_in_recepcion_es != ""){ ?>`

Comment: Using `empty` is a much better idea than directly comparing to a blank string

Comment: @DevWithZachary, Yes you are also right. but his specified variable is a string, not an array so why can use the empty function.

Answer (score -2):

Hello You can do it like this :

```
<?php 
    if (isset($con_in_recepcion_es)) {
      echo " <div class='container contenerdor_dideo'>
          <iframe src='$con_in_recepcion_es' width='640' height='360' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; fullscreen; picture-in-picture' allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
          <form method='POST' action='auditorio.php' name='formulario1'>
            <input type='text' name='con_in_recepcion_ori' value='$con_in_recepcion_ori'>
            <input type='text' name='con_in_recepcion_esp' value='$con_in_recepcion_es'>
            </div><a href='javascript:enviar_formulario()' onclick='window.location='auditorio.php''  ><div id='button-forum-plenarios' >
            <i class='fas fa-globe iconForo'></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Audio Original</b>  </div></a>
           </form>";
    
    }
 ?>
```

This is how you can add your HTML tags inside echo statement and inside your if condition

Comment: This doesn't take into consideration variables having a blank value from the post data

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what happens is that if the html is shown, but not my variable already defined at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @juliofernandez here if your variables are not set, the loop will not execute.

Comment: so they have to be defined inside the loop? even if they are fuzzy outside?

Comment: You need to defined outside the loop (if statement). If they are empty or is not set the condition gets false. And the if block won't execute

Comment: using `empty` makes `isset` redundant, you don't need both